# Extracting auto incremented id

Tags: javascript

I have this code;

```
$scope.hold = {};

$scope.save = function (){
    var data = {
        parent_id: $scope.hold.id, //-->This is an auto generated id.
        name: $scope.hold.some_name,
        address: $scope.hold.address,
        dependent = {
                     parent_id: $scope.hold.id, //--> This is equal to the id above. 
                     child_name: $scope.hold.child_name,
                     child_age: $scope.hold.child_age
        }
    }
myService.saveData(data, function(){
})
}
```

Now, I am not able to get the auto incremented id, I cannot log it too. It returns undefined. From where I made a mistake? How I may able to get my auto incremented id? This is in order to fulfill my query in my api.

The `dependent` inside `var data` is to be saved into another model, which has a foreign key of that `id`.

How I may able to extract my auto incremented `id`(parent table), so that I can initialize it to my child's `id`(dependent table) in order to perform a single **HTTP POST** method.

**TABLE DESIGN (sample)**

`**Parent Table**
parent_id  | name | address
1          | john | place`

`**Dependent Table**
dependent_id | parent_id | name | age
2            |    1      | james|  7`

Comment: Is `$scope.hold.id` ever defined? I don't see anywhere in the code where you are giving it a value, so it would make sense that it's `undefined`.

Comment: I really don't understand what are you trying to do. `$scope.hold` in your case is empty object. So, `data.id` is `undefined` because `$scope.hold.id` is `undefined` too. And if you want data to be object, you need to write so: `var data = {id: something, name: other_value...}`

Comment: Sorry, the `$scope.hold` is the one I used in binding on my html.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek That's it exactly sir. I mean, how can I define my `$scope.hold.id` using my auto incremented id (incremented on/by database).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem with your code is the JSON object your are creating.

it should be like below

```
var data = {
    id : $scope.hold.id, //-->This is an auto generated id.
    name : $scope.hold.some_name,
    address : $scope.hold.address,
    dependent : {
                 id:$scope.hold.id, //--> This is equal to the id above.
                 child_name:$scope.hold.child_name,
                 child_age:$scope.hold.child_age
    }
}
```

Snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 
 $scope.hold = {};
 
 $scope.hold.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

$scope.save = function (){
    var data = {
        id : $scope.hold.id, //-->This is an auto generated id.
        name : $scope.hold.some_name,
        address : $scope.hold.address,
        dependent : {
                     id:$scope.hold.id, //--> This is equal to the id above.
                     child_name:$scope.hold.child_name,
                     child_age:$scope.hold.child_age
        }
    }
    
alert(data.dependent.id);    
    
}

});
```

```html
 

 <html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>dynamic ID {{hold.id}}</p>
     <a ng-click="save()"> click here to save</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What I mean on the auto generated is in its database, sir. Like auto incremented data

Comment: I am so sorry 'bout the confusion, sir.

Comment: For that you will have to first save the data object using HTTP post , in the response you should return the auto incremented ID, in the success call back assign this ID to dependent object and then save it using HTTP post.

Comment: Is there any other way using only one HTTP Post? Because I am using only 1 Post method.

Comment: There can be one more approach but that's a little tricky and cause issue in case of concurrent operations. For that first thing make sure that your auto incremented ID , always increment by a definite number. Second thing is , you need to fire a get call to get the last record entry in the table where you storing data. In this record, you will have the last record ID, increment this ID with definite increment number as per your first step. Now associate this ID with dependent object.

Comment: Since it's already been defined in the database as auto incremented, so yes, it will always increment. Second, I cannot visualize on how to fire up a GET call when I am suppose to do POST method. This my code looks like, sir.
`Parent newParent = new Parent{
//some entities
}
JObject child = (JObject)data;
JToken value;
if(child.TryGetValues("dependent", out value))
{
newParent.Dependents.add(new Dependents{
//some entities
}
}`

This is what's inside of my POST method, sir.

Comment: check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/livWUVlquhbPgdhkSdiG it will give you and idea of what i am suggesting above.

Comment: Thank you for taking time with that plunker sir. Your idea is great, but, I guess, I cannot apply it in mine. If there's only other way than having 'comment convo' in here. I may explain it to you well.

Comment: hi sir, I've been thinking 'bout the plunker you gave to me. I just wanna ask, why will I get the last record id?

Comment: it will be used to predict the next record id of the table where you storing data. you can use this to set the value of  data.dependent.id

Comment: Meaning, I will be getting the last entry in the database -> have it incremented set the value to data.dependent.id? Did I get it sir?

Comment: yes, this is the way, but be sure your application is not accessed concurrently by more than one users, this approach is not valid for concurrent operations.

Comment: Let's say that my application will be used only by one user. Will that be not a problem in the future? I mean, the `dependent.id` is a foreign key from `data.id` which is auto incremented. I will edit my post and have my database sample design. Please see edit, sir.

Comment: yes,it should not be a problem, just put both of your call under transaction, if one fails , rollback both. This will maintain data integrity and system will work fine.

Comment: Have you seen the design sir? With which design, will it still not be a problem?

Comment: yes, the design will work fine, hope you have implemented the foreign key constraint properly in the DB, in case of any misshaping, that will save you from loosing data integrity.

Comment: I guess the implementation of foreign key is fine. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: Now I am able to get it, however, new problem occur. Perhaps, another question on SO may do. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: glad that i could help, you can mark the answer complete if it helped you to achieve what you wanted in this SO question.

Answer (score 0):

How about another way?

```js
function Man(name, age)
{
  this._id = Math.round(Math.random() * 8999 + 1000);
  this._name = name || null;
  this._age = age || 0;
  this._address = null;
  this._dependent = null;
}

Man.prototype.getId = function()
{
  return this._id;
}

Man.prototype.getName = function() 
{
  return this._name;
}

Man.prototype.setName = function(name)
{
  this._name = name;
  return this;
}

Man.prototype.getAge = function()
{
  return this._age;
}

Man.prototype.setAge = function(age)
{
  this._age = age;
  return this;
}

Man.prototype.getAddress = function()
{
  return this._address;
}

Man.prototype.setAddress = function(address)
{
  this._address = address;
  return this;
}

Man.prototype.getDependent = function()
{
  return this._dependent;
}

Man.prototype.isDependent = function()
{
  return this._dependent ? true : false;
}

Man.prototype.setDependent = function(dependent)
{
  this._dependent = dependent;
  return this;
}

Man.prototype.logInfo = function()
{
  console.log('id: ' + this._id);
  console.log('name: ' + this._name);
  console.log('age: ' + (this.age > 0 ? this.age :  '-'));
  console.log('address: ' + (this._address ? this._address : '-'));
  console.log('dependent: ' + (this._dependent ? this._dependent.getId() : 'no'));
}



var Jane = new Man('Jane', 41);
Jane.setAddress('NY, Miracle str., 5');
var Max = new Man('Max', 20);
Max.setAddress(Jane.getAddress()).setDependent(Jane);
Jane.logInfo();
Max.logInfo();
```

Comment: This is a great way, sir. However, this may not meet what I asked above. I am so sorry, I guess I made my question above kind of confusing.